# Can't connect to docker redis

Tags: docker, spring-boot, redis

I have a docker-compose file which contains next image:

```
redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

I expected that container name will be exposed and i'll be able to connect using redis:6379 uri, but i can't do it. Here's the config:

```
fun jedisLocalConnectionFactory(): JedisConnectionFactory {
    val jedisConFactory = JedisConnectionFactory()
    jedisConFactory.hostName = "redis"
    jedisConFactory.port = 6379
    return jedisConFactory
}
```

How to expose this redis service and connect to it?I've tried a lot of different combinations without any luck..

Comment: If you shell into the container, can you see if redis is in fact listening on port 6379?  Try  'netstat -na | grep 6379' when you get in there.  Could be that it's listening on localhost only and that's not allowing the port translation to happen correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting using container name can only work with user defined network. Here is capture from Docker documentation

> Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default bridge >network. If you want containers to resolve IP addresses by container name, >you should use user-defined networks instead. 
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Use this as reference :

```
services:
  springboot:
    image: springboot
    networks:
      - my-net

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - my-net

networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added my-net from this example. Which uri i can use to access the service?

Comment: You can access it directly as `redis`. Or give it a network alias.